# Social Registration in Yii?

Tags: yii, social-networking

How to integrate Facebook,Twitter and Googleplus registration in yii?

Is there any widget in yii? Plz tell me Solution for social registration

in yii? Itried,

widget('application.widgets.facebook.Facebook',array('appId'=>'YOUR_APP_ID')); ?>

But i got error
Dwoo::widget not found like this

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into this link. I think it may help.

[hybridauth (social media into Yii framework)](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hybridauth/)

Just download the extension and follow the steps.

Comment: Thanx for ur reply, How to run controller when controller name and module name same in yii?